# Joining two arrays in an order

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that i need to join and then return at the end of the function. Here is what is in both arrays is the style of `print_r()`

Array 1:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Main Door
        [1] => Clock
        [2] => Production corridor
        [3] => Warehouse Corridor
        [4] => Production corridor
        [5] => Warehouse Corridor
        [6] => Production corridor
)
```

Array 2:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => 08:04:14
        [1] => 08:04:29
        [2] => 08:07:10
        [3] => 08:36:34
        [4] => 08:40:40
        [5] => 08:58:33
        [6] => 09:00:58
)
```

So these two arrays correspond with each other so Main Door out of the first array goes with `08:04:14` out of the second array and so on, so what would be the best way to put these two arrays in to one where they are joined like that?

Comment: What about making an associative array where it would be array("Main Door" => 08:04:14 ,... )? would that be acceptable in your situation?

Comment: So what do you want the result to look like?  An array of arrays (for example, `array(array('Main Door', '08:04:14'), array('Clock', '08:04:29')...)`?  Or an associative array where, for example, `$array['Main Door']` would be equal to `08:04:14`?  Or an array of some sort of object that includes both values?  Or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want results like `array('Clock', '08:04:29')`:

```
array_combine($a1, $a2);
```

otherwise:

```
$new = array();
foreach($a1 as $k => $v) {
  $new[$k] = array($v, $a2[$k]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

eg:

```
<?php
    $array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
    $array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
    $result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

and go through the below link for more examples,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
$a1 = array(0 => 'main door', 1 => 'clock');
$a2 = array(0 => '08:04:14', 1 => '08:04:29');
$length = count($a1);
$a3 = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
  $a3[] = array($a1[$i], $a2[$i]);
  // if you want to keep the indexes the same, use $a3[$i] instead
}
var_dump($a3);
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ef165727122cae87ebb13dd5ebe6e4cf828025d)



Using that code you can access the data like this:

```
$desc = $a3[0][0]; // main door
$time = $a3[0][1]; // 08:04:14
```